# ubuntu 13.04 damaged google earth

Tags: 13.04, google

After upgrade to ubuntu 13.04 google earth stopped working in versions 6 and 7.
in 6.---- the fly to function quit working and in version 7.---- the fly to works but no 
user uploaded pics will display all you get is a blank white box and on some, when you click the mouse on them G.E. shuts down. I know this is a ubuntu caused problem because I just installed G.E.  in windows 7 and it is fully functional. Ubuntu forums shows that many or maybe all users of 13.04 have this problem.Surely by this time someone has taken time to find the fix. I don't have programming skill so I can't do so.

Harlie

further result.....

I went back to ubuntu 12.04 and now it too will not work properly with google earth
in ver. 7.- - - - so now it's back to windows for G.E.

Harlie

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Google Earth will solve your problem.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall google-earth-stable
```

Comment: Thank you I will do this and hope it solves the problem.

Comment: Well a double thank you I did as you said and now the pictures are viewable like normal. One remaining issue is the fly to function does not work as before all you get is a small box saying   'invalid HTTP can you comment on this? I can live without it but it sure was nice if you didn't know where a particular city was located. Again thanks.